# Manually project coordinates similar to gluLookAt in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, projection, pyopengl

I'm trying to implement viewing matrix and projection, similar to gluLookAt to get the view position of each 3D coordinate. I have implemented something that seems close to working but is reversed. 
For example - the following code gets the correct position (When I actually don't change the coordinates. But if I change the up-vector to point towards X instead of Y, I get reversed coordinates.

```
import numpy as np

def normalize_vector(vector):
    return vector / (np.linalg.norm(vector))

def get_lookat_matrix(position_vector, front_vector, up_vector):
    m1 = np.zeros([4, 4], dtype=np.float32)
    m2 = np.zeros([4, 4], dtype=np.float32)

    z = normalize_vector(-front_vector)
    x = normalize_vector(np.cross(up_vector, z))
    y = np.cross(z, x)

    m1[:3, 0] = x
    m1[:3, 1] = y
    m1[:3, 2] = z
    m1[3, 3] = 1.0

    m2[0, 0] = m2[1, 1] = m2[2, 2] = 1.0
    m2[:3, 3] = -position_vector
    m2[3, 3] = 1.0

    return np.matmul(m1, m2)

def get_projection_matrix(near, far):
    aspect = 1.0
    fov = 1.0  # 90 Degrees
    m = np.zeros([4, 4], dtype=np.float32)

    m[0, 0] = fov/aspect
    m[1, 1] = fov
    m[2, 2] = (-far)/(far-near)
    m[2, 3] = (-near*far)/(far-near)
    m[3, 2] = -1.0
    return m

position_vector = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=np.float32)
front_vector = np.array([0, 0, -1], dtype=np.float32)
up_vector = np.array([0, 1, 0], dtype=np.float32)

viewing_matrix = get_lookat_matrix(position_vector=position_vector, front_vector=front_vector, up_vector=up_vector)
print("viewing_matrix\n", viewing_matrix, "\n\n")
projection_matrix = get_projection_matrix(near=0.1, far=100.0)
point = np.array([1, 0, -10, 1], dtype=np.float32)

projected_point = projection_matrix.dot(viewing_matrix.dot(point))
# Normalize
projected_point /= projected_point[3]
print(projected_point)
```

And it happens with many changes of the coordinates. I'm not sure where am I wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gluLookAt` defines a 4*4 viewing transformation matrix, for the use of OpenGL.

A "mathematical" 4*4 matrix looks like this:

```
  c0  c1  c2  c3            c0  c1  c2  c3
[ Xx  Yx  Zx  Tx ]        [  0   4   8  12 ]     
[ Xy  Yy  Zy  Ty ]        [  1   5   9  13 ]     
[ Xz  Yz  Zz  Tz ]        [  2   6  10  14 ]     
[  0   0   0   1 ]        [  3   7  11  15 ]
```

But the memory image of a 4*4 OpenGL matrix looks like this:

```
[ Xx, Xy, Xz, 0, Yx, Yy, Yz, 0, Zx, Zy, Zz, 0, Tx, Ty, Tz, 1 ]
```

See [The OpenGL Shading Language 4.6, 5.4.2 Vector and Matrix Constructors, page 101](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf)
and [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.20 Specification, 5.4.2 Vector and Matrix Constructors, page 100](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf):

> To initialize a matrix by specifying vectors or scalars, the components are assigned to the matrix elements in **column-major order**.
>
> ```
> mat4(float, float, float, float,  // first column
>      float, float, float, float,  // second column
>      float, float, float, float,  // third column
>      float, float, float, float); // fourth column
> ```

Note, in compare to a mathematical matrix where the columns are written from top to bottom, which feels natural, at the initialization of an OpenGL matrix, the colums are written from the left to the right. This lead sto the benefit, that the x, y, z components of an axis or of the translation are in direct succession in the memory. This is a big advantage when accessing the axis vectors or the translation vector of the matrix.
See also [Data Type (GLSL) - Matrix constructors](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Matrix_constructors).

This means you have to "swap" columns and rows (transpose) of the matrix:

```
def get_lookat_matrix(position_vector, front_vector, up_vector):
    m1 = np.zeros([4, 4], dtype=np.float32)
    m2 = np.zeros([4, 4], dtype=np.float32)

    z = normalize_vector(-front_vector)
    x = normalize_vector(np.cross(up_vector, z))
    y = np.cross(z, x)

    m1[0, :3] = x
    m1[1, :3] = y
    m1[2, :3] = z
    m1[3, 3] = 1.0

    m2[0, 0] = m2[1, 1] = m2[2, 2] = 1.0
    m2[3, :3] = -position_vector
    m2[3, 3] = 1.0

    return np.matmul(m1, m2)

def get_projection_matrix(near, far):
    aspect = 1.0
    fov = 1.0  # 90 Degrees
    m = np.zeros([4, 4], dtype=np.float32)

    m[0, 0] = fov/aspect
    m[1, 1] = fov
    m[2, 2] = (-far+near)/(far-near)
    m[3, 2] = (-2.0*near*far)/(far-near)
    m[2, 3] = -1.0
    return m
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a minor change you must do:

```
m[2, 2] = -(far+near)/(far-near)       //instead of m[2, 2] = (-far)/(far-near)
m[2, 3] = (-2.0*near*far)/(far-near)   //instead of m[2, 3] = (-near*far)/(far-near)
```

The big thing is the row/column order of your matrices.

As @Rabbid76 pointed out, mayor column order is preferred. GLSL provides a function to transpose a matrix. You can also tell to transpose the matrix when it's passed to GPU with `glUniformMatrix` family commands.

Let's see how to work with row mayor order matrices, as your code does.

The goal, by now with CPU, is to get: `finalPoint = matrixMultiply(C, P)` with `C` the combined matrix and `P` the point coordinates. `matrixMultiply` is any function you use to do matrices multplication. Remember the order matters, A·B is not the same as B·A

Because `C` is a 4x4 matrix and `P` is 1x4, C·P is not possible, it must be P·C.
Notice that with column order `P` is 4x1 and then C·P is the right operation.

Let's call `L` the look-at matrix (proper name is *view matrix*). It's formed by an orientation matrix `O` and a translation matrix `T`. With column order is `L= O·T`.

A property of transposed matrix is (A·B)<sup>t</sup> = B<sup>t</sup> · A<sup>t</sup>

So, with row order you get O·T = O<sub>c</sub><sup>t</sup> · T<sub>c</sub><sup>t</sup> = (T<sub>c</sub> · O<sub>c</sub>)<sup>t</sup> where `c` is for column order. Hey! what we wish is (O<sub>c</sub> · T<sub>c</sub>)<sup>t</sup>  Notice the change in order of multiplication?

So, if you work with row mayor order matrices, the order they are multiplied is swapped.

The view&projection combined matrix also must be swapped.

Thus replace:

```
return np.matmul(m2, m1)   //was return np.matmul(m1, m2)
```

and

```
//was projected_point = projection_matrix.dot(viewing_matrix.dot(point))
projected_point = point.dot(viewing_matrix.dot(projection_matrix))
```

Despite of all of above, I recommend to work with column mayor order. That's best for OpenGL. And you'll understand better any maths and tutorials you find on OpenGL.